# Entity framework Attach actualiza sólo las propiedades modificadas ¿por qué?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy usando el siguiente código para actualizar muchas entidades en la BD. Utilizo `AutoDetectChangesEnabled=false` por eso, porque si no le cuesta mucho tiempo. De esta manera se reduce mucho el tiempo.

Aquí modifico la lista de ítems

```
ActualizarItems(ítems);

public void ActualizarItems(List<Item> ítems){
    DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(item);
    }
    DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Pero mi pregunta es ¿por qué funciona sin indicar explícitamente las propiedades que han cambiado, es decir, sin poner la línea de modificación después de Attach?

```
DbSet.Attach(item);
DbContext.Entry(item).Property(u => u.Puntos).IsModified = true;
```

Yo pensaba que siempre había que indicar las propiedades que se habían modificado, pero con el código que he puesto no es necesario hacerlo. `Attach` detecta las propiedades que han cambiado respecto a lo que hay en BD y genera el comando Update añadiendo sólo las propiedades que han cambiado.

¿Alguien me puede explicar este comportamiento?

**Edición**

He hecho pruebas. El estado de los objetos antes y después del `Attach` es `Unchanged`. Pero justo después de activar `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, el estado pasa a `Modified`.

```
public void ActualizarItems(List<Item> ítems){
   DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      //Aquí el estado es sin cambios
       DbSet.Attach(item);
     //Aquí el estado es sin cambios
   }
   DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

   //Aquí el estado es modificado
   DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

El caso es que este comportamiento desconcertante me viene bien, ya que evita tener que indicar explicitamente las propiedades que modifico, él las detecta.

Pero no me da seguridad utilizar esto así hasta que no tenga una respuesta lógica.

---

No sé si esto nos ayuda. ¿podeis echarle un vistazo?

https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/

Comment: En efecto, un `Attach` por sí solo no debería generar ningún `update` cuando le haces un `SaveChanges`. Sospecho que el ejemplo que incluístes en la pregunta no está completo. ¿Puedes asegurarte de incluir un [mcve]?

Comment: Si no me equivoco @sstan, en el momento en el que se modifica una propiedad de una entidad, `IsModified` se pone a true para dicha propiedad,con lo que `Attach` generaría un update de esa fila solo con ese campo. No es asi?

Comment: @Pikoh: Exacto, siempre y cuando el `Attach` ocurre *antes* de modificar dicha propiedad.  Pero si modificas un entity, y *después* le haces un `Attach`, el estado del entity pasa a `Unchanged`, por lo que el `SaveChanges` no genera ninguna modificación a la base de datos.  Con el ejemplo en la pregunta, no queda claro dónde sucede la modificación de las propiedades del entity.

Comment: Entiendo. La modicación debe producirse despues del attach para que se genere el update. Gracias por la explicación @sstan , no soy nada fan de EF :)

Comment: Aclaro que la entidad (ítem) la modifico antes de llegar a este código. El código que he puesto esta completo, es lo que tengo en el cuerpo de un método que recibe List<ítem> ítems.

Comment: @Patxi: Si lo que dices es cierto, estoy de acuerdo contigo que hay un misterio. ¿Pudieras verificar el `state` del entity inmediatamente antes y después del `Attach` y compartir con nosotros el resultado (`DbContext.Entry(item).State`)? Lo normal sería que diga `Detached` antes, y `Unchanged` después.

Comment: Mañana haré la prueba que me pides. Yo pienso lo mismo: la entidad está desconectada del contexto y tras el Attach debería estar en el contexto pero sin cambios. El caso es que en la práctica no es así ya que detecta únicamente las propiedades modificadas y con el Profiler veo esto que comento.

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar en SO ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes que me parece que exactamente habla de lo que estan hablando uds. Si sirve, @sstan queres traducirla? o la traduzco y la hago wiki...

Comment: @gbianchi: Lo que menciona el enlace se parece, pero en realidad es un problema distinto ya que no tiene que ver con el uso de `Attach` que es una parte importante de esta pregunta.

Comment: Opino lo mismo, el enlace que aportas no se refiere a este problema que yo expongo.

Comment: Y, aunque no creo que haga diferencia, pudieras probar quitando las sentencias que cambian el `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, solo para ver si afecta en algo lo que observas.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205)

Si analizamos lo comentado en el link

comenta que compara la entidad con lo que tiene en el `snapshot` cuando la entidad ha sido consultada o esta adjunta, o sea si haces un query a la entidad y luego realizas el attach esa comparacion es la que anulas

lo que tendrias que intentar seria

```
DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
foreach (var item in items)
{
  DbSet.Attach(item);
}

DbContext.SaveChanges(); 

DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

realiza el SaveChanges() antes de volver habilitar el "auto detect changes"